# How does the summation of a partial binomial should be resolved?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-distribution

I stumbled on a question that I cant do. Here is:
In a casino roulette game, we have 18 red cases, 18 green ones and one blue (made up roulette game). We are interested on 2 players that, for every game, bet on the red cases. If the marble goes on one of the red cases, the player gets 2 times the amount he bets. 
Say one of the players has 10 dollars and plays 10 games and hes betting 1 dollar for each game on the red. What is the expectation of his money after 10 games?

1. I tried doing it with summation and the answer that it should give me is $2.10.\frac{18}{37}  -10$ , but im stuck on this :

$$\Bbb E(X=i)=  \sum_{i=0}^{20} i \binom{20}{i} (\frac{18}{37})^{i} (1- \frac{18}{37})^{20-i} $$ $$\downarrow$$

$$\Bbb E(X=i)= (\frac{19}{37})^{20} \sum_{i=0}^{20} \frac{20!}{(i-1)!(20-i)!} (\frac{18}{19})^{i} $$
$$\downarrow$$
$$ ?$$

I don't know how to get this done.

2. I didn't get the other way of doing it which is 
   $$\Bbb E(X)=n(2p-1) $$

thanks for the help !

Comment: esperance $\rightarrow$ expected value

Comment: @Rserrao Im actually downloading Maplesoft for this but its taking too much time and I think the i and the 20-i are right by the equation of a binomial

Comment: I now see what is wrong, i will edit my answer asao. Try and understand it: X does not take all values from 0 to 20 and you only play 10 times thus the n in the bin. coefficient should be a 10. When I can I'll come back to help more

Comment: @Rserrao the possible values of X are 0, 1, 2,..., 20 
Therefore, 
$$ \Bbb E(X)= 0.P(X=0) + 1.P(X=1)+ 2.P(X=2) +....$$
$$ \Bbb E(X)= 0. \binom{20}{0} (\frac{18}{37})^0 (\frac{19}{37})^{20-0} + 1.\binom{20}{1} (\frac{18}{37})^1 (\frac{19}{37})^{20-1}+ 2.\binom{20}{2} (\frac{18}{37})^2 (\frac{19}{37})^{20-2} ...$$
it goes from 0 to 20 because you can get 0 after u spend ur whole 10 dollars in 10 games and win 20 in 10 games

Comment: @Rserrao I tried it on maplesoft but I get an error when I type the equation :
> (19/37)^20*(sum(factorial(20)*(18/19)^i/(factorial(i-1)*factorial(20-i)), i = 0 .. 20));
the error is :Error, (in SumTools:-DefiniteSum:-ClosedForm) summand is singular in the interval of summation

Comment: The point here is: no, you cannot get all values from 0 to 20 :) you have ten games. Say you lost $i $ times. Hence you won $10-i $ times. You started with 10 dollars. Everytime you lose, you lose 1 dollars. Everytime you win; you win 1 dollar, hence $10 - i - (10 - i) = 20 - 2i $ are the possible values of $X $ :) not convinced? How would you end up with 1 dollar? Or 3? Or 5? Create one specific example of how he would do that. You may want to check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one individual play, you bet one dollar. $-1$. And then with $p $ chance you get $2$ dollars back. Then the expected value for that play is $2p -1$.

If you play 10 times, and knowing that the outcome of one play does **not** depend on the others, the right answer will be arrived at by summing the expected value of one play, 10 times, hence making

$10\cdot (2p -1) = 2*10p - 10$

And the last formula is

$n\cdot (2p - 1)$

And not

$np2 - 10$

Because of the expected value for one single play.

Now on to the summation part. Set $X $ as his final money. Start by noticing that if the player lost $i$ times (and therefore won $10-i $) then he ended up with $10 - i + (10 - i) = 20-2i $ dollars. That is, we have $X \in \{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20\} $.

When $X = 20 - 2i $ for some $i $, $i $ denotes the number of losses. The probability of having $X = 20-2i $ is given by the chance that we won exactly $10-i $ games times the chance that we lost exactly $i $ games times the number of permutations win/loss we can have to achieve that result. Hence we get

$$\Bbb P(X = 20-2i) = {10\choose {i}} \left (1 - \frac {18}{37}\right)^i\left(\frac {18}{37}\right)^{10-i} $$

And thus the expected final money ought to be the weighted sum of those probabilities, the value times the probability we got that value. Note that the expected money is *initial money* $+$ *expected value*.

$$\Bbb E(final\ money) = \sum_{i=0}^{10} (20 - 2i)P(X = 20 - 2i) = \sum_{i=0}^{10} (20 - 2i){10\choose {i}} \left (1 - \frac {18}{37}\right)^i\left(\frac {18}{37}\right)^{10-i}$$

I asked WolframAlpha how much this was and got the right answer: he said the expected money was $\frac{360}{37} $ and thus the expectation value for the 10 plays was $\frac{360}{37} - 10 = -\frac{10}{37}$

[image: value of the evaluated summation]

which matches the formula $20p - 10 = 20\cdot \frac{18}{37} - \frac{370}{37} = -\frac{10}{37}$

Comment: I think you are right. There is a mistake in my book it is like you said : $n.(2p-1)$
Thank you

Comment: any idea on the summation I have done ?

Comment: @user387171 i will try to get it. Have you understood my answer though? Do you understand the formula now?

Comment: I completely understood. Thank you ! Im sorry I forget to check for accepted answer, Im new here and Im not sure how everything works.

Comment: @user387171 i am completely clueless about the purpose of your summation, sorry :( if you edit your question with *how* your summation should work, then I can try to get what is wrong. Welcome here though. Just be sure to never post a question without trying to find the answer for yourself and **always** write what you did/try and your insights of the problem so we can help you the best we can.

Comment: Thanks dude I added up one equation and I dont know how to get the summation done afterward. Ive never seen anything like this before so Im blondsighted

Comment: dude ur amazing ! thank you sooo muchhhhh :) !